# Tool vs Python Script for Transforming Data in Mongo

Tags: data-cleaning

We have a bunch of Mongo collections (data collected from APIs, web scraping, etc) that we need to transform to a cleaner data structure (standardized schema) on a monthly basis. Are there any good tools to help us manage this process, or would you recommend writing a Python script instead?

Comment: I'd look into [mongo's Spark connector](https://www.mongodb.com/products/spark-connector); Spark simplifies ETL.

Answer (score 1):

Many ETL tools support MongoDB and are commonly used for normalizing and standardizing data. For example:

http://www.pentaho.com/analytics-for-mongodb#tab-2